# My js script is to toggle "active" class between selections on a sidebar menu but only allows toggling for the first selection

Tags: javascript, css

My issue is I am only able to toggle "active" class on my first "side-menu" div and not the others. Please take a look at my codes and let me know what is wrong.

When active, there will be a span on the left showing that it is the current selection, refer to the attached image.

HTML SCRIPT

```
            <div class="sidebar">
            <div class="side-menu">
                <a class="side-option" href="#beverages"><img src="images/beverage.png" alt=""></a>
                <p>Beverages</p>
            </div>
            <div class="side-menu">
                <a class="side-option" href="#burger"><img src="images/burger2.png" alt=""></a>
                <p>Burger</p>
            </div>
            <div class="side-menu">
                <a class="side-option" href="#pizza"><img src="images/pizza1.png" alt=""></a>
                <p>Pizza</p>
            </div>
            <div class="side-menu">
                <a class="side-option" href="#pasta"><img src="images/pasta2.png" alt=""></a>
                <p>Pasta</p>
            </div>
            <div class="side-menu">
                <a class="side-option" href="#sides"><img src="images/sides1.png" alt=""></a>
                <p>Sides</p>
            </div>
            <div class="side-menu">
                <a class="side-option" href="#desserts"><img src="images/desserts1.png" alt=""></a>
                <p>Desserts</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS SCRIPT

```
.side-menu.active p::after{
content: '';
background-color: var(--clr-primary);
width: 10px;
height: 100px;
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 5px;
```

JS SCRIPT

```
let sidemenu = document.querySelector('.side-menu')
let fbg = document.querySelector('.food-box-grid')
sidemenu.onclick=function(){
  sidemenu.classList.toggle('active')
  fbg.classList.toggle('active')
}
```

[I can toggle active class on the "beverages" but not on the other options such as burger, pizza...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRNFX.png)

Answer (score 1):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

> querySelector() returns the first Element within the document that matches the specified selector

You want to use `querySelectorAll()`, then iterate through the output and toggle the class for each element.

Something like this

```js
let sidemenu = document.querySelectorAll('.side-menu')
let fbg = document.querySelectorAll('.food-box-grid')
sidemenu.onclick=function(){
  sidemenu.forEach((i) => {
    i.classList.toggle("active")
  })
  fbg.forEach((i) => {
    i.classList.toggle("active")
  })
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help, do i need to change anything in css script after changing my js scrip to queryselectorall?

Comment: Nope, once you change the class for all the elements, css will apply to all of them

Comment: The reason why I am asking about the css script is that after changing to "queryselectorall", it does not work anymore not even on the first element

Comment: Could you post your new JS code?

Comment: I tried just changing queryselector to querselectorall as well as your example

Comment: Try the new code I posted
I didn't realize querySelectorAll() returned a NodeList instead of a normal array

Comment: thanks for helping but it is still not working